# Angular 5 http.delete not sending Form data params

Tags: angular, angular-http

I have the following code:

```
const requestData = {
    id: 123
};
this.http.delete(APIURL, {params: requestData})
    .subscribe(() => {
         do_something
    }, () => {
        log_error
    });
```

For some reason, the .delete is not sending the params to the URL
How can I make it send the params similar to a POST (form data)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the id in the url

```
this.http.delete(APIURL + '/' + requestData.id)
    .subscribe(() => {
         do_something
    }, () => {
        log_error
    });
```

Comment: I think that depends in your endpoint, what are using ? I use asp.net core and to delete I have to pass the Id in the url and no body.